# Scrolling malfunction

Tags: technical-issues, pokemon-go, android

My phone has 3 years and when im in a Pokemon window, and want to go all the way down in order to release it, the scrolling is very difficult.

I need to tap very close to the screen lateral border and even like this i need 3-4 attempts to scroll until the release button.

Is the lag? is my phone? Any suggestions?

Comment: Does it lag when playing the game? Is the game from the official store or is the game incompatible and you used the apk to install it?

Comment: @dly  is the official one and except this one, i have no lags or problems regarding the phone.

Comment: Then I'm pretty sure the phone has no problem with the game itself. What phone is it?

Comment: @dly HTC One M7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you've figured this out already, but **try using two fingers**. Like a dual finger scroll (like something you would do on a laptop touchpad). It always works for me. It saved so me much time after I figured that out! I guess they didn't exactly make it user-friendly for most phone users, but at least it works now :)

Comment: i didnt figured out since i cant change my phone (yet) and reinstalling do not do the trick. i'll try later and let you know! thanks

Comment: oh god, you are a genius, that works wonders!

Answer (score 1):

It's because your phone is quite old. Either you need to get a new one or reinstall. Then again Pokemon Go does take up a lot of space.

Comment: It's not just about the device's age. My phone is older and quite good at running the game.

Comment: well, could be the age. reinstalling is not a solution. until a new phone, i have to deal with it i guess .. thanks ^^

Comment: you could try restoring your phone to fabric status, that for sure will help. I think I will do that myself with my Moto G2

Comment: It's all about helping people.